# File txt: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python

i have a txt file and if i try to open it python says:

```
runfile('/Users/costanzanaldi/Desktop/tesi/Tesi_Naldi/COdice _Python/untitled0.py', wdir='/Users/costanzanaldi/Desktop/tesi/Tesi_Naldi/COdice _Python')

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-30-b4bdfdd17ca2>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/Users/costanzanaldi/Desktop/tesi/Tesi_Naldi/COdice _Python/untitled0.py', wdir='/Users/costanzanaldi/Desktop/tesi/Tesi_Naldi/COdice _Python')

  File "/Users/costanzanaldi/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 685, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/Users/costanzanaldi/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 85, in execfile
    exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/Users/costanzanaldi/Desktop/tesi/Tesi_Naldi/COdice _Python/untitled0.py", line 13, in <module>
    in_file = open("POLO_SCIENTIFICO_(LAMMA).txt","r")

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'POLO_SCIENTIFICO_(LAMMA).txt'
```

1)the file EXISTS!
2)the path is correct! It is in the desktop!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your directory to your desktop in order to access the file. You'd do that using the `os` module, like this:

```
import os
os.chdir("/path/to/Desktop")
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably this means the file is not on the desktop. (I assume you changed Ethan's "/path/to/Desktop" to the correct path in your system, which is "/Users/costanzanaldi/Desktop"?). Wherever it is, you need to give open() the full path to POLO_SCIENTIFICO_(LAMMA).txt unless you have chdir'd to the correct directory. I assume you have got the letter-case correct in POLO_SCIENTIFICO_(LAMMA).txt :-)